What is the Joint Probability Density Function of two Normal Random Variables?
Let $X_1, ... , X_n \in \mathcal{U}(-1,1)$ be independent random variables and define $Y = \sum_{k=1}^n (X_k - b)^2$ and $Z = \sum_{k=1}^n (X_k - c)^2$. I want to find the joint probability density function
$$
P(Y \leq y, Z \leq z)
$$ but I am not able to figure out how.
work so far
I know from C.L.T. that
$$
Y \to^d \mathcal{N}(n \cdot \mu_b, n \cdot \sigma_b^2) \hspace{0.5cm} Z \to^d \mathcal{N}(n \cdot \mu_c, n \cdot \sigma_c^2)
$$ where $\mu_b, \sigma_b^2$ is the mean and variance of $(X_k - b)^2$ (and the same for the others). Is the a standard way to continue?
I also think that one can consider
$$
\begin{bmatrix} Y\\ Z \end{bmatrix} \to \mathcal{N} \left( \begin{bmatrix} n \cdot \mu_b\\ n \cdot \mu_c \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}n \cdot \sigma_b^2 & ... \\ ... & n \cdot \sigma_c^2 \end{bmatrix} \right)
$$
An answer for the limit case is ok for me

I don't see how the CLT helps you here. That's a limiting case. Also your title does not really reflect your question.

Please edit the title if you have a good improvement ... I know that my random variables are somehow particular ... but that is the best I could come up with

I can see you suggested some edit, but I do not know how to accept that ... Do I need to click something or what?

There should be an accept edit button or something of that sort.

"This suggested edit to your post has already been handled and your action is no longer required." some bot canceled your edit

It can be shown that the joint distribution of $Y_n,Z_n$ in the limit $n\to\infty$ is a bivariate normal distribution. In fact, it can be shown that
$$(\bar{Y}_n, \bar{Z}_n)=\left(\frac{Y_n-\mathbb{E}(Y_n)}{\sqrt{n}},\frac{Z_n-\mathbb{E}(Z_n)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\mathop\sim^{n\to\infty} \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$$
$$\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{60b^2+4}{45}&\frac{60bc+4}{45}\\\frac{60bc+4}{45}&\frac{60c^2+4}{45}\end{pmatrix}$$
To show this, one has to compute the exponential generating function for the joint distribution, which reduces to
$$\mathbb{E}\left(e^{-t_1 Y_n- t_2 Z_n}\right)=\left(\mathbb{E}\left(e^{-t_1 (X-b)^2- t_2 (X-c)^2}\right)\right)^n=\left(\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{2} ~e^{-t_1(x-b)^2-t_2(x-c)^2}\right)^n$$
It is not hard to show that all the moments of this distribution are finite and the exponential generating function for the normalized variables can be expanded around $t_1=t_2=0$, and hence converges in the limit to:
$$\mathbb{E}\left(e^{-t_1 \bar{Y}_n- t_2 \bar{Z}_n}\right)=\left(1+4\frac{(15b^2+1)t_1^2+2(15bc+1)t_1t_2+(15c^2+1)t_2^2}{45n}+o(n^{-3/2})\right)^n\to \exp({t^T\Sigma t})$$
which is the GF of the distribution stated above.
Finally, the GF can also be analytically expressed in terms of the error function:
$$\mathbb{E}\left(e^{-t_1 Y_n- t_2 Z_n}\right)=\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4\sqrt{t_1+t_2}}e^{-t_1t_2(b-c)^2}\left[\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t_1+t_2}-\frac{t_1b+t_2c}{\sqrt{t_1+t_2}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(-\sqrt{t_1+t_2}-\frac{t_1b+t_2c}{\sqrt{t_1+t_2}}\right)\right]\right)^n$$
It seems unlikely that this expression can lead to an explicit inversion and hence a formula for the joint PDF, however.

Now that we know that joint distribution for $Y,Z $ is the bivariate normal, I can use (for the limit case) the associated p.d.f. of the bivariate, right?

The exact same limit case is obtained by using C.L.T., right?

That is correct.
